# How to add margin-top to hyperlink inside bootstrap col/form?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to beautify a form in bootstrap. I don't understand why I can not add some margin to a hyperlink thats below an input? I tried to remove bootstrap and that didn't work, so I don't think it has something to do with bootstrap!

https://jsfiddle.net/k8ws75je/

```
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">


    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" required autofocus>


                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong></strong>
                </span>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" required>


                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong></strong>
                </span>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <a id="linkpassword" href="#">Change Password</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                Update
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
#linkpassword{
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `a` elements are `inline` elements, which cannot have vertical margins. Change it to an  `inline-block` to make it work

```
#linkpassword{
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/knu1badd/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#linkpassword{
  margin-top: 400px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it `display: block`. Thus it will be as you want.

Answer (score 0):

warp `a` element in a `div` block and apply the position/margin on this block.
Because `a` is an inline element.

```
<div class="margin-top">
   <a id="linkpassword" href="#">Change Password</a>
</div>
```